# Найти n пар простых чисел, которые отличаются друг от друга на 2

Tags: c#

нужно решить задание: Не используя массива найти n пар простых чисел, которые отличаются друг от друга на 2. Вот мой код, но не могу придумать как его доработать.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        bool prim = true;
        // Для каждого значения i проверяется деление без
        // остатка на числа от 2 до i/2
        for (int j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                prim = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (prim)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Для облегчения понимания сути вопроса, напишите пожалуйста в сам вопрос входные данные и желаемый результат.

Comment: Отвлекитесь от кода. Опишите словами, как бы Вы искали эти пары.

Comment: Должно получиться что-то такое: "2 и 3, 3 и 5, 5 и 7, 7 и 11, 13 и 17"

Comment: Вот видите, все гораздо хуже, чем мы думали. Самый первый (и самый трудный) шаг - внимательно прочитать и *понять* задание: *... простых чисел, которые отличаются друг от друга на 2*, `7 и 11, 13 и 17`

Comment: Я бы искал так: Если от простого числа вычесть 2 и получиться предыдущее простое число, тогда это нужная пара

Comment: Igor, Там опечатка

Comment: Нет, там нет опечатки. А "там" - это где?

Comment: так эти числа не "отличаются друг от друга на 2"

Comment: ответ имеется от самого автора, но он не отмечен.

Answer (score 0):

Решением данного задания будет:

```
        static bool IsPrime(int x)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i * i <= x; i++)
            if (x % i == 0) return false;

        return true;
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        int n = 10; // число пар
        for (int i = 2, j = 1; j <= n; i++)
            if (IsPrime(i) && IsPrime(i + 2))
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2}", j++, i, i + 2);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```